# CSS - Style the last 3 li of an ul

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an `ul` with 7 `li` inside of it. I know that I can style the first and last `li` but is it possible to style the last 3 `li`'s so the text is a different colour? This is the first time I have come across this problem/dilemma. I have googled around a bit and have not found much that is really helping me.

```
<div class="international-portfolio">
<div class="international-portfolio-title"> Sales Representation International</div>
<ul class="nobullet inline int-portfolio ">
<li class="excelsior-hotel-ernst first">
<li class="le-mas-candille">
<li class="mandarin-oriental-hotel-group-worldwide">
<li class="victoria-jungfrau-grand-hotel-spa">
<li class="palace-luzern">
<li class="eden-au-lac">
<li class="bellevue-palace last">
</ul>
</div>
```

ive updated the coding - trying the solutions given but not working at the moment but will keep at it.

Comment: look for pseudo-class :nth-child - but that's CSS3, so no consistent browser support yet

Comment: Seems to be supported in all major browsers, except IE: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t39

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the trick (but mind you, it won't work in older versions of IE):
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild

Use the css selector as follows:

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  /*stuff here*/
}
```

Here's an example, too:
http://jsfiddle.net/yAUwb/

Comment: Nice! (Your Fiddle uses -n+3, instead of -n+4.)

Comment: You're spot on about that; however, short of getting into JavaScript, you won't be able to pull it off purely via CSS in the lesser browsers. At least I think.

Comment: @Romanulus - im going to leave it as it is - IE9 is working fine - that is more than enough - thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
li:nth-last-child(1), li:nth-last-child(2), li:nth-last-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Updated. Thank you BoltClock.

Comment: But this answer should be a bit more compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda of possible with this code

```
.myList li:nth-last-child(1),
.myList li:nth-last-child(2),
.myList li:nth-last-child(3)
{
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2np58/